# Google Maps API - "road" distance between 2 points

Tags: google-maps, distance, driving-directions

I have a website where "near locations" are shown for each item, based on the latitude and longitude coordinates stored in a database.

Problem is that this calculated distance is the air-line distance, which differs a lot ferom the actual driving distance.

Google Maps does only have a JavaScript API for driving directions by now, I need it as a web service API to make calls directly from the server.

Is there any possibility to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Maps API has a HTTP service for geocoding, but not for directions.  You can only access that functionality through the Javascript API.  You could hack it, but it would break Google's ToS.

More discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949754/).

Comment: Thanks. I think I will not do it by "hacking"/using the raw HTTP requests. Looping through my items, calculating the distance via the JavaScript API and writing the results back in my database seems to be a good solution for now.