# Use the google maps API to compute the driving time between two points on an iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, cocoa-touch, google-maps, driving-directions

Hey guys. I have an iphone application that sorts locations based on how long it would take to get there. Is there a way to use google maps (or something similar) to find the travel time between point A and B? There was a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470309/google-maps-api-road-distance-between-2-points) on this forum over a year ago that said it can only be done in javascript. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042885/using-google-maps-api-to-get-travel-time-data)  gives a javascript example. Is there a way to run this javascript in cocoa-touch, or does the google maps API now support this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check out
https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions